# Transformation from one space to another and keep a custom sorting rule

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, transformation

I wasn't sure if this is the appropriate StackExchange site, but I feel it is the closest one to my problem.

My problem includes a transformation from a finite subset of $\mathbb Z^n$ to $\mathbb Z$ that my custom sorting rule still applies. Let me give you an example of a simplified version of $\mathbb Z^4$.

Let's say that we have a vector $(x,y,z,w)\in\mathbb Z^4$ where

- $0\le x\le30$
- $0\le y\le100$
- $5\le z\le10$
- $0\le w\le10000$

The sorting rule works like this:
if

- $a_1=(x_1,y_1,z_1,w_1)$
- $a_2=(x_2,y_2,z_2,w_2)$
- $a_3=(x_3,y_3,z_3,w_3)$

then $a_1\le a_2 \le a_3$ only if

- $x_1\le x_2\le x_3$
- $y_1\le y_2\le y_3$
- $z_1\le z_2\le z_3$
- $w_1\le w_2\le w_3$

**Question 1**

The problem looks like that:
I want to find a function $f(x,y,z,w) = k \in \mathbb Z$ such that $f(a_1) \le f(a_2) \le f(a_3) \implies a_1\le a_2 \le a_3$.

In practice, if I know only the $k_1$ and $k_3$ and one gives me the $x_2,y_2,z_2,w_2$, I will use the function to get the $k_2$ and compare them with the $k_1$ and $k_3$.

**Question 2**

What if the sorting rule has a few parameters $=$ instead of $\le$, like

- $x_1\le x_2\le x_3$
- $y_1\le y_2\le y_3$
- $z_1\le z_2\le z_3$
- $w_1 = w_2 = w_3$

How does this affect the function?

**Question 3**

Can we extend the above to $\mathbb Z^n$ where $n \le 100$?

Comment: Doesn't $f(a)=x+y+z+w$ suffice?

Comment: Let's say we have $a_1=(5,0,5,0)$ and $a_3=(10,0,5,0)$. The suggested function means $f(a_1) = 10$ and $f(a_3) = 15$. However, the $a_2 = (0,7,5,0)$ has $f(a_2) = 12$ which is between $10<12<15$ but doesn't fit the rule of sorting in the question

Comment: So actually the logical order should be "$f(a_1)\leqslant f(a_2)\leqslant f(a_3)\Rightarrow a_1\leqslant a_2\leqslant a_3$" instead of "$a_1\leqslant a_2\leqslant a_3\Rightarrow f(a_1)\leqslant f(a_2)\leqslant f(a_3)$".

Comment: Notice that you're comparing $f(a_1)\leq f(a_2)\leq f(a_3)$, but what you equivalently need is that $f(a_1)\leq f(a_2) \implies a_1 \leq a_2$. This implies and is implied by what you require.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that your question is equivalent to $f(a_1)\leq f(a_2) \implies a_1 \leq a_2$.

Such an $f$ would have to be injective.
Indeed, if $f(a_1) = f(a_2) \iff f(a_1)\leq f(a_2)$ and $f(a_2)\leq f(a_1)$ then $a_1 \leq a_2$ and $a_2 \leq a_1 \iff a_1 = a_2$.

Hence, whenever $a_1 \neq a_2$, $f(a_1) \neq f(a_2)$ and since $\mathbb Z$ is totally ordered we would necessarily have (relabeling if necessary) $f(a_1) < f(a_2)$.
But the order you imposed on $\mathbb Z^n$ is partial, and so whenever $a_1$ and $a_2$ are incomparable, the property you wish for will fail.

Comment: Do you mean that the problem is not solvable and there isn't any function that can pass the order rule I need?

Comment: Yes, no such $f$ exists for any $n\geq 2$.